# Color of menu button in toolbar

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

[image: Screenshot]

How to set any color for these three points?

Comment: It worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502469/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-menu-in-a-custom-created-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

> How to set any color for these three points

You seem to have Light theme set for your app or activity. Set it to Dark one and dots will be show light.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as your base `style`.

**OR**

You can change `overflow icon` color by changing `android:textColorSecondary` in your style:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do.

```
  <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```