# How do I change the color of menu in a custom created toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-menu

I have a homepage where I have created a custom toolbar, and now I need to add the menu items to it. So far I have been successful and I have my `search` icon in `app:showAsAction="always"` mode (which is white) but when I add anything in `app:showAsAction="never"` mode then the menu indicator(three dots) appear as black in color, but I want them white.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomePage"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

**actvity_homepage.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        style="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:background="#2B772E"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**homepage_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/logoutmenu"
    android:title= "Log Out"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout"
    app:itemIconTint = "#ffffff"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Hello" />
</menu>
```

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(first way) in your style :**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">#62ff00</item>
</style>
```

**Or you can change it with toolbar style like this:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  ...
  theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
/>
```

and in your style:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#333333</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The first method worked but not the second one somehow. Thanks a lot anyway!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to be the simplest answer.

```
toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```